# SQL from JoinWith() is separated from main ActiveQuery, making OnCondition() throw unkown column error

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I'm using a Gridview based on my table (i'm calling `TABLE0`) and i have a search form as well. Here is a sample of my table and the other tables related to it:

**TABLE0**

```
ID | TALBE1_ID | (more fields)
```

**TABLE1**

```
ID | TABLE2_ID | TABLE3_ID | (more fields)
```

**TABLE2** and **TABLE3**:

```
ID | (more fields)
```

As we can see, `TABLE1` have a relation with both `TABLE2` and `TABLE3`.

My current problem is when i try to make my search form. Depending of a field from `TABLE1` (in this case, `FIELDCHECK`), i will use one of the search parameters (in this case `customAttribute`) to search a specific column from `TABLE2` or `TABLE3` (and the column does not have the same name).

Here is my current search (not working):

```
public customAttribute;
// more attributes, but not using at the moment

public function search($params)
{
    $query = self::find()->orderBy(['TABLE0.FIELD0' => SORT_ASC]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->joinWith([
        'relationTable1' => function ($query1) {
            $query1->andFilterWhere(['in', 'TABLE1.FIELDCHECK', ['0','1','2','3']])
            // more ->andFilterWhere([]) but i'm not using at the moment
            ->joinWith([
                    'relationTable2' => function ($query2) {
                        $query2->onCondition(['TABLE1.FIELDCHECK' => '0']) // if FIELDCHECK is 0 i will do this join.
                            ->andFilterWhere(['TABLE2.FIELD2' => $this->customAttribute]);
                    }
                ])
                ->joinWith([
                    'relationWithTable3' => function ($query3) {
                        $query3->onCondition(['<>', 'TABLE1.FIELDCHECK', '0']) // if FIELDCHECK is not 0 i will do this join instead
                            ->andFilterWhere(['TABLE3.FIELD3' => $this->customAttribute]);
                    }
                ]);
        }
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

This is throwing an sql error:

```
General error: 4104 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [4104] (severity 16) [(null)]
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM [TABLE2] WHERE ([ID] IN ('163203002', '163202002', '163203001', '163203004', '163203003', '163202001', '163202003', '163202004', '161201005', '161201012', '161201020', '161201021', '161201022', '161201023', '161201034', '161201042', '161201043', '161201046', '161201701', '161201047')) AND ([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK]='0')
```

Ok, with this error i can see that the `joinWith` sql is running separated from the main query (after getting the ids). But if i try to get the sql generated by this `$query` with `$query->createCommand()->sql` i got:

```
SELECT [TABLE0].* FROM [TABLE0]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE1] ON [TABLE0].[TABLE1_ID] = [TABLE1].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE2] ON ([TABLE1].[TABLE2_ID] = [TABLE2].[ID]) AND ([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] = '0')
LEFT JOIN [TABLE3] ON ([TABLE1].[TABLE3_ID] = [TABLE2].[ID]) AND ([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] <> '0')
WHERE [TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] IN ('0','1','2','3') ORDER BY [TABLE0].[FIELD0];
```

And running this query, it works fine. I know i can try to use a raw sql in this Gridview (probably with [ArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html), but i still not sure how), but i really want to make this `ActiveDataProvider` work.

I removed all irrelevant code here, but I commented in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution.

So, the main problem here is, when i use a `joinWith()`, i can't call any of the tables outside the joined table in my `onCondition()` method. I figured out that instead of doing this query (obs: the commented code is the `andFilterWhere()` condition):

```
SELECT [TABLE0].* FROM [TABLE0]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE1] ON [TABLE0].[TABLE1_ID] = [TABLE1].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE2] ON ([TABLE1].[TABLE2_ID] = [TABLE2].[ID]) AND ([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] = '0') // AND ([TABLE2.FIELD2] = $this->customAttribute)
LEFT JOIN [TABLE3] ON ([TABLE1].[TABLE3_ID] = [TABLE3].[ID]) AND ([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] <> '0') // AND ([TABLE3.FIELD3] = $this->customAttribute)
WHERE [TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] IN ('0','1','2','3') ORDER BY [TABLE0].[FIELD0];
```

I can do this query instead:

```
SELECT [TABLE0].* FROM [TABLE0]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE1] ON [TABLE0].[TABLE1_ID] = [TABLE1].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE2] ON [TABLE1].[TABLE2_ID] = [TABLE2].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE2] ON [TABLE1].[TABLE3_ID] = [TABLE3].[ID]
WHERE (
    (([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] = '0') /* AND ([TABLE2].[FIELD2] = $this->customAttribute) */)
    OR
    (([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] <> '0') /* AND ([TABLE3].[FIELD3] = $this->customAttribute) */)
)
AND ([TABLE1].[FIELDCHECK] IN ('0','1','2','3'))
ORDER BY [TABLE0].[FIELD0]
```

Here  is the final **search**:

```
public customAttribute;
// more attributes, but not using at the moment

public function search($params)
{
    $query = self::find()->orderBy(['TABLE0.FIELD0' => SORT_ASC]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->joinWith([
        'relationTable1' => function ($query1) {
            $query1->andFilterWhere(['in', 'TABLE1.FIELDCHECK', ['0','1','2','3']])
            // more ->andFilterWhere([]) but i'm not using at the moment
            ->joinWith(['relationTable2', 'relationWithTable3']);
        }
    ]);

    $query->andFilterwhere([
        'or',
        ['and', ['TABLE1.FIELDCHECK' => '0'], ['like', 'TABLE2.FIELD2', $this->customAttribute]],
        ['and', ['<>', 'TABLE1.FIELDCHECK', '0'], ['like', 'TABLE3.FIELD3', $this->customAttribute]]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```